# Many To Many with additional data using Swift and Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, swift4

I do a lot of apps (two tier apps) with SQL server, and this is my first app in iOS with core data.

I am trying to figure out how to do Many to Many relation with additional data. Let me explain that with simple example:

first Entity called  List (referring list of products) and it has one attribute listName.

second entity called product (referring products) and it has one attribute productname.

Each "product" can be in more than one "List" and each "List" contain more than one "product".

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2urCf.png)

Xcode has created automatically the joined table:

[SQLLITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hFap.png)

My problem now is I cannot figure out how to add for example a "quantity" column for this joined table. My main objective is to say:

In list1 I have **4 product1**

In ***list2*** I have **3 product1**

In ***list2*** I have 4 product2

...

In SQL server is too simple since I create my self this joined table and add additional data, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing in core data.

Comment: Use an intermediate entity (ie a explicit join table).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37889958/3985749) for example.

Comment: thank you. it is crystal clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data hides the correlation table if you use Many-2-Many (without any additional attributes). This means, in the inverse way, that you need to create a correlation table yourself. You can do this, if you create a new Entity in Core Data, which should have a 2-One relationship to both other Entities.

Without extra attributes:

Entity1 <-> Entity2 (The correlation table is hidden, but is there)

With extra attributes:

Entity1 <- CorrelationEntity(with extra attributes) -> Entity2

Comment: It means the traditional way to create many to many relationship still valid in core Data. What was confusing for me is Apple documentation about automatically handle the joined table.

Comment: Yes, it does handle the join table automatically, but only if there are no extra attributes.